Error Creating a new React App all the time - Version 19.0.0, dependencies of 18.0.0 or something
PS C:\Users\Nanda Kumar\Desktop\Wyvern\Web Dev\MERN\ReactJS\my-app> npm start

my-app@0.1.0 start
react-scripts start

Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'
Require stack:

C:\Users\Nanda Kumar\Desktop\Wyvern\Web Dev\MERN\ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\definitions\typeof.js
C:\Users\Nanda Kumar\Desktop\Wyvern\Web Dev\MERN\ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\keywords\typeof.js
C:\Users\Nanda Kumar\Desktop\Wyvern\Web Dev\MERN\ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\keywords\index.js
C:\Users\Nanda Kumar\Desktop\Wyvern\Web Dev\MERN\ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\index.js
C:\Users\Nanda Kumar\Desktop\Wyvern\Web Dev\MERN\ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js
C:\Users\Nanda Kumar\Desktop\Wyvern\Web Dev\MERN\ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\index.js
C:\Users\Nanda Kumar\Desktop\Wyvern\Web Dev\MERN\ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js
C:\Users\Nanda Kumar\Desktop\Wyvern\Web Dev\MERN\ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js

At the beginning, i had this problem which is stated in the title, but then somehow it got resolved when i added two new folders, npm and npm-cache and all (with the help of ChatGPT)
i then added that package by installing, everything went well
But then i was working with my project, i was not able to import css files at all
like i am able to import js files, but not the css even when they are in the same folder
The problem
I was trying to learn react in VS Code, and then all these errors, please help me!
